# Mysql fetch query with variable input?

Tags: php, sql, variables

I'm trying to do a retrieval of data from a table on my server but the only problem is every user has a different "company_id" attached to their account and I have to retrieve in specific to each user.

Each one comes in the form of "po_12345678" so I thought something like

```
$poresults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM po_" ? $_SESSION['company_id']);
```

might work but I have had no luck. I feel like the answer should be simple and I'm just missing something easy... Help on this would be great!

Comment: I would suggest looking into using PDO (PHP Data Objects) http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php, parameterising your variables and using prepared statements. mysql_functions are being deprecated. You can do what you're asking using mysql_query but it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `po_".$_SESSION['company_id']."`");
```

Also:

1. Dont use mysql_query, use PDO or MySQLi
2. Though session is not an input directly from user, but you still should escape it, it is very important

Comment: Can you explain the second part of your answer? Why is it so important? Protecting privacy leaks and what not?

Comment: @NathanGeist first, this session data might have came from the user at the first point (in signup page etc), even if not, it might contain characters that would break the SQL (quotes, etc) , why not always escape your query data instead of thinking on whether or not it is from user and if you should escape it (which might not be true)

Comment: @NathanGeist Also mysql_query is deprecated already, so using PDO or MySQLi (MySQL+Improved)  is smarter and safer, if you find it hard to work with PDO or MySQLi , simply use a php framework (such as CodeIgniter) or a light php database framework (such as Medoo.in)